# Get latest tag from specific branches

Tags: git, git-branch, git-tag

I am trying to figure out a way to get the latest tag between two branches. This way I can see what the latest version number is across all of my version branches.

Let's say I have the following structure:

```
o  - master tag=v1.1.3
|
|o - v1.1 tag=v1.1.2
||
|/
o  - tag=v1.0.2
|
|o - v1.0 tag=v1.0.1
||
|/
o
```

I would like to be able to get the commit that has the latest version number, that isn't on master, but is on any branch that conforms to the v1.* pattern. In this example, it would give me the tag of v1.1.2. I have tried the following:

```
git describe --tags --match="v*" `git rev-list --tags --branches="v1\.*" --max-count=1 ^master`
```

This only gets me the absolute latest tag out of the whole repository, and returns v1.1.3. I've tried creating another branch that was arbitrarily named, and had a new tag associated with it, and it returns that latest tag. Is there something else I am missing, or is my understanding of rev-list flawed?

Comment: What does "the latest version number" mean here?

Comment: Which tag are you expecting to get back?

Comment: I would expect to get v1.1.2 back.